# Modeling archive/current repository in doctrine

Tags: sql, database-design, doctrine, entity, dql

Assume there is a abstract doctrine class named "file" and child classes "archiveFile" and "currentFile" which are represented by a discriminator column "file_type" ... in my application, only one "currentFile" can exist and multiple "archiveFile". If new files are imported, the newest of this imported file is now the current file and the previous file should move to an archive file ...

In theory, it works fine. But in practice i cannot change the type neither of the currentFile nor the archiveFile ... is there a better approach for my intention or have i to deal with plain sql to set the discrimination column?